# Calculating Probability using a chessboard

Tags: probability

We have a coin with radius `r` and surface `pi*r^2` and a `3x3` chessboard, the coin's center is equally distributed along the board.

$E$ = event that the coin with same probability, randomly lands fully in $(B,2)$ (no coin parts are out of the square)

Book answer, which I don't understand :

$P(E) =(1-2r)^2/9$  if $ 0\le{r}\le1/2$ and

$P(E)=0,otherwise$

Why is mine wrong ?

$P(E) = \pi r^2/9$  for $ 0\le{r}\le1/2$ ?

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information given to answer this question.  Please describe what it means for the coin to land in a square--must it be wholly within it or just its center or something else--and then tell us the probability law governing its location.

Comment: @whuber done :)

Comment: Thank you, but your question is still missing the crucial information about the probability law.  Without that, literally any answer between $0$ and $1$ is possible.

Comment: @whuber hopefully it's enough now, I'm struggling to translate it accurately.

Comment: Thank you!  Here's a hint: this is purely a geometry problem.  Just draw a picture showing where the coin's center could lie if the coin is entirely contained in square B2.  The area of that region is proportional to the probability (because the distribution is uniform across the entire board).

Comment: Your question doesn't state the size of the sides of the chessboard squares. Is it $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instant way to see why your answer is wrong is to consider that if the coin were infinitesimally small, the probability would be 1/9th for randomly falling in (B,2). Further, this probability is smaller when the coin is bigger for, the centroid may fall in (B,2) with the same probability but its edges then fall out: either falling on the horizontal side(s) or the vertical side(s).

What then is the effect of considering larger coins? A smaller square must be drawn within (B,2) to be the geometric space in which the *centroid* of our measurable coin will fall. The border must be spaced from the edges of (B,2) by a distance of $r$, so the lengths of its edges are $(1-2r)$ and its area is $(1-2r)^2$, relative to (B,2) (which has area 1/9 relative to the entire board).

Comment: @Oleg I think you are confused by my answer. Consider first the instance where the coin is infinitesimally small: it is easy to visualize the problem as a matter of a grain of sand falling in a square. If the "coin" then has volume to it, it is an equivalent problem to think of the centroid of the coin falling into an inscribed square. By considering only the centroid of the coin, we are back to the "grain of sand" problem. It just needs to stay within its bounds. I am not saying the square is a random object.

Comment: The area of B2 is $1$, not $1/9$: these are unit squares.  The correct rationale is that a uniform distribution on the entire board assigns a probability of $1/9$ per unit area.

Comment: @whuber the question doesn't actually seem to say anywhere that these are unit squares (though presumably they should be); at least I take the "3x3" to be the usual sense of counting, rather than measuring the squares and I don't see anything else that suggests a dimension for the squares.

Comment: @Glen_b This answer claims "the lengths of its edges are $(1-2r)$," which implies a linear unit of measurement has implicitly been chosen in which the squares have unit area, not area $1/9$.  Although the ultimate formula is correct (how could it not be, when it's given in the question itself?), the justification is erroneous--albeit easily fixed.